# Can you construct a different derived class based on a parameter passed?

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm wondering if something like this is possible...

```
class Thing
{
        public Thing(int i)
        {
        }
}

class DerivedThing : Thing
{
        public DerivedThing(int i)
        {
        }
}

_thing = new Thing(0)

_derivedthing  = new Thing(1)
```

If you pass 0 you get a Thing, if you pass 1 you get a DerivedThing
This is not complete, just an illustration.. But basically I'm wondering if/how you could return different derived classes based on the value of a parameter passed to the baseclass constructor? 
Or do you just need another bit of code which decides which constructor to call?

Comment: You're probably looking for some kind of Factory pattern.

Comment: Why a base class? Why not a class factory of some sort?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question: no, it is not possible. But...

You are actually looking for a `Factory` pattern. You can easily add a distinguishing if/case in a factory method and still have a relatively clean code.

[Factory pattern description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible.

Instead, you can make a `static Thing Create(int i)` method that decides which constructor to call.

Answer (score 1):

No, and why do you want to?

You may as well type

```
var thing = new Thing();

var derivedThing = new DerivedThing();
```

You could something like,

```
public static class ThingFactory
{
    public interface IThing {}

    public enum ThingType
    {
        Thing,
        DerivedThing
    }

    public static IThing CreateThing(ThingType type)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case ThingType.DerivedThing:
                return new DerivedThing();

            default:
                return new Thing();
        }
    }

    private class Thing : IThing {}

    private class DerivedThing : Thing {}
}
```

Allowing,

```
var thing = ThingFactory.CreateThing(ThingType.Thing);

var derivedThing = ThingFactory.CreateThing(ThingType.DerivedThing);
```